# Getting error message when trying to run a powershell script that performs a silent install of an application

Tags: windows, powershell, openvpn

I am trying to perform a silent install of an application. (I'm doing this so that I can deploy it silently to other users in our domain)

The program I'm trying to silently install is OpenVPN. Here is the PowerShell script that I'm currently attempting to run.

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Computer Name you are accessing'


########## Install Software On PC ##########

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\c$\temp\openVPN"

    Copy-Item "Z:\(15) IT\VPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-1602-Win7.exe" "\\$Computer\c$\temp\openVPN" -Recurse

    Write-Host "Installing openVPN on $Computer"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-1602-Win7.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait} 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-1602-Win7.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait} 

########## Remove temporary files and folder on each PC ##########

    Write-Host "Removing Temporary files on $Computer"
    $RemovalPath = "\\$Computer\c$\temp\openVPN"
    Get-ChildItem  -Path $RemovalPath -Recurse  | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
    Remove-Item $RemovalPath -Force -Recurse
```

But I am receiving a couple of error messages when I run the script. The first error I encounter is that it says is

> `Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'Z:\(15) IT\VPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-1602-Win7.exe' because it does not exist`

(It does exist) And then the 2nd error I receive is

> Connecting to remote server (Computer Name) failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 5.1.17763.771 @Jawad

Comment: Yeah not sure how that happened, think I accidentally took it out testing different things. But anyways, it matches now and still gives the same error @Jawad

Comment: @Jawad I think it may be a stackOverflow error because when I go to edit the question the "\" is there

Comment: are you running this script with the user and computer that has the Z: drive mapped? If you have Z: drive on your profile, it doesnt necessarily means other profile would have it as well (like administrator or different Run As User)

Comment: Yeah I'm testing the script on my computer and I have it mapped @Jawad

Comment: Are you running the script elevated?  Even if you've mapped a drive normally, it isn't always visible in elevated prompts: [Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt ...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co)

Comment: Yes I am. And I just tried moving it to my C: but got the same "Cannot find path 'C:\openvpn-install-2.4.8-1602-Win7.exe' because it does not exist"  @Jawad

Comment: In powershell ISE, Write `Copy-Item C:\open" and then press tab to see if it fills in the name for you. if it does, write C:\temp as the destination (make sure C:\temp exists) and see if that works. If it does, there is some spelling issues with your file name since your script is having issues even finding the file on C: drive

Comment: Okay yes dumb mistake. The file script had a '1' when the actual file was a "I".. oops. Now I just have the " Connecting to remote server (Computer) failed with the following error message : The client
cannot connect to the destination specified in the request." error @Jawad

Comment: can you connect to the $computer outside of the script? what happens when you try `Enter-PSSession $computer` ? Is there any firewall blocking your call (port 5985)

Comment: I get the same error outside of the script @Jawad

Comment: i'm hoping you are not asking us what you should do when there is a firewall issue

Comment: Yeah sorry I had checked the windows firewall issues and they were fine so was confused. I have been informed that we run ESET on the domain and I didn't know about that so that was my problem. Thanks for the help! @Jawad